# /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn': No such file or directory - node (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app

Running cli `shopify create`

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli

Results in the following error:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn': No such file or directory
>   - node (Errno::ENOENT)

On Windows (within Ubuntu WSL) I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/bin/shopify:36:in `<main>'
        32: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:21:in `call'
        31: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/error_handler.rb:75:in `handle_abort'
        30: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/bin/shopify:37:in `block in <main>'
        29: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:18:in `call'
        28: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/core/monorail.rb:25:in `log'
        27: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/core/entry_point.rb:19:in `block in call'
        26: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/core/executor.rb:17:in `call'
        25: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:14:in `call'
        24: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:45:in `with_traps'
        23: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:57:in `twrap'
        22: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:46:in `block in with_traps'
        21: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:53:in `twrap'
        20: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in with_traps'
        19: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:15:in `block in call'
        18: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:37:in `with_logging'
        17: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui.rb:143:in `log_output_to'
        16: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:38:in `block in with_logging'
        15: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-ui/lib/cli/ui/stdout_router.rb:164:in `with_id'
        14: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in with_logging'
        13: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/executor.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in call'
        12: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/commands/create.rb:8:in `call'
        11: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/command.rb:24:in `call'
        10: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/commands/create.rb:25:in `call'
         9: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/sub_command.rb:12:in `call'
         8: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/project_types/node/commands/create.rb:26:in `call'
         7: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/project_types/node/commands/create.rb:72:in `check_node'
         6: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/lib/shopify-cli/context.rb:268:in `capture2e'
         5: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/system.rb:68:in `capture2e'
         4: from /home/neil/.shopify-app-cli/vendor/deps/cli-kit/lib/cli/kit/system.rb:176:in `delegate_open3'
         3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:390:in `capture2e'
         2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:208:in `popen2e'
         1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `popen_run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn': No such file or directory - node (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Link to the issue at GitHub: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli/issues/552

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: was able to fix it by installing node (nodejs on ubuntu)
p.s. thanks to @tanema for pointing it out

Comment: Which nodejs did you install, the apt package or the snap package? The snap package is easier to update and lets you choose a custom version for each project.

Comment: @karel not sure; probably the default one of: `apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 2):

was able to fix it by installing node (nodejs on ubuntu) p.s. thanks to @tanema for pointing it out: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-cli/issues/552

to install node:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall